# Getting error "Invalid Subsidiary Combination" after submitting Timesheet record in Netsuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am updating timesheet record through client script but on Submitting the record getting an error as "Invalid Subsidiary Combination".

PS: I am working on 15.2 latest version of Netsuite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue with one of our cost rollup script that works with time tracking(timebill) - check the accounts related the employee/project/labor item etc - if the accounts are not exposed to the subsidiaries in question - this can happen.Also if you are using consolidation or elimination subsidiary, make sure that those are not the subsidiaries in context. In our case one project was mistakenly assigned to our consolidation subsidiary thus causing subsidiary mis-match.

Comment: OK, Thanks.!
I am using nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('timegrid','sunday', '5'); in line init function. 
The line is edited properly but while saving the record, it throws an exception.
If I remove my client script and manually edit and save. It works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

That error message usually means the subsidiary and employee location don't match.  i.e. the employee and/or their location are not part of the subsidiary you specified.